# Wordpress' Advanced Custom Fields text overflows DIV

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm using ACF in wordpress for the simplest purpose, adding a description field.

PHP

```
<div id="description-div">
    <p><?php the_field('description'); ?></p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#description-div {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
}

#description-div p {
    width: 250px;
}
```

But no matter how I enclose the text (tried with and without p and divs, giving them a width), it always overflows the parent divs. 
Here's the live example: http://no-plans.com/temp/wp-tobias/wordpress/?p=35

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this:

```
#description-div p {
width: auto;
line-height: 1;
white-space: normal;
}
```

Line 526 of your CSS file is over-riding #description-div, I'd suggest looking at the structure of your CSS rules and seeing how they cascade, I suspect you're getting inheritance issues.

Using a good CSS Reset will help here too.